# Calling a function from macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the function: `Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row` to determine the last row with data. This and similar formulas appear in many spots in my VBA code. My spreadsheet is quite complex and I often need to add columns. So rather than referring to Column 14, I'd like to use a value I can easily change in only one place. I am using a named Column of sorts that I only need to update in one place. Items sold appears in column N. I realize that this code is very simple, but I simplified it down for the sake of asking a question. When I try to run the Test sub, I a compile errror: ByRef argument type mismatch and the variable Item_Sold. The reason I am using a letter is that `Range()` needs a letter, but `Cells().End(xlUp).Row` needs a number.

It works if I move:  `Items_Sold = "N"` to the sub from the function, but this means this code would have to go in every sub rather than in just one function.

Function:

```
Function ColNum(ColumnNumber As String) As Integer
Dim Items_Sold As String
Items_Sold = "N"
ColNum = Range(Replace("#:#", "#", ColumnNumber)).Column
End Function
```

Macro:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Total_Items_Sold As Integer
Total_Items_Sold = Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum(Items_Sold)).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: You already seem to be hardcoding the column letter - why not just use a int variable for the column number?

Comment: You may be getting an error because when you call the functino `ColNum(Items_Sold)`, `Items_Sold` is not a declared variable and so is treated as `Empty`, which is a numeric/int, but your function is expecting a string...

Comment: @DavidZemens Good thought but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg because in most places I will reference it with Range() which wants the letter, not a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Global constant.

At the top of your module, outside of any Sub/Function:

```
Const COL_NUM As Long = 14
```

Usage:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Total_Items_Sold As Long
    Total_Items_Sold = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, COL_NUM).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a global variable at the beginning of the code by writing

```
public Items_Sold as String
```

that will solve your **ByRef** problem. But still you will have problem with undeclared value of **Items_Sold** when invoking **Test()** unless you set the value of **Items_Sold** somewhere before.